# How can I disable the scroll-into-view behavior of TScrollBox?

Tags: delphi, scroll

I have a `TScrollBox` that has a RichEdit that is bigger than the scrollbox, so both side scrollbars appear in the scrollbox. Then I have a function `DoTask` that calls `RichEdit.SetFocus`.

When I scroll down to where I want to see part of the text control, and then call `DoTask`, the ScrollBox will automatically scroll to the top of the RichEdit. How can I avoid that?

Comment: don't use the scroll box seems to be the obvious solution since you have more scroll bars than needed

Comment: @David: if the RichEdit is the only component on the scrollbox, I agree. Of course we don't know if it is. Putting a single component that has its own scrollbars on a scrollbox would be a little... weird, indeed.

Comment: yes, there are many controls aside from richedit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you wish, here are some suggestions:

- Override `SetFocusedControl` in the form:

  ```
  function TForm1.SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean;
  begin
    if Control = RichEdit then
      Result := True
    else
      Result := inherited SetFocusedControl(Control);
  end;
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  type
    TCustomMemoAccess = class(TCustomMemo);

  function TForm1.SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean;
  var
    Memo: TCustomMemoAccess;
    Scroller: TScrollingWinControl;
    Pt: TPoint;
  begin
    Result := inherited SetFocusedControl(Control);
    if (Control is TCustomMemo) and (Control.Parent <> nil) and
      (Control.Parent is TScrollingWinControl) then
    begin
      Memo := TCustomMemoAccess(Control);
      Scroller := TScrollingWinControl(Memo.Parent);
      SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_POSFROMCHAR, Integer(@Pt), Memo.SelStart);
      Scroller.VertScrollBar.Position := Scroller.VertScrollBar.Position +
        Memo.Top + Pt.Y;
    end;
  end;
  ```
- Interpose `TScrollBox`:

  ```
  type
    TScrollBox = class(Forms.TScrollBox)
    protected
      procedure AutoScrollInView(AControl: TControl); override;
    end;

  procedure TScrollBox.AutoScrollInView(AControl: TControl);
  begin
    if not (AControl is TCustomMemo) then
      inherited AutoScrollInView(AControl);
  end;
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  procedure TScrollBox.AutoScrollInView(AControl: TControl);
  begin
    if (AControl.Top > VertScrollBar.Position + ClientHeight) xor
        (AControl.Top + AControl.Height < VertScrollBar.Position) then
      inherited AutoScrollInView(AControl);
  end;
  ```

Or use any creative combination of all of the above. How and when you like it to be scrolled only you know.

Comment: I guess a class helper for TScrollBox, instead of an interposer, would also do the trick. Can't check that, though.

Comment: I don't think that would work, @Rudy. You can't override virtual methods with class helpers. The original call site of the method doesn't know the class helper exists, so it will continue to call the original method.

Comment: @Rob: You are right. The original call site won't use the helper method.

Answer (score 2):

the simpliest solution would be

```
var a, b : Integer;
begin
  a := ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position;
  b := ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position;
  richEdit1.SetFocus;
  ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position:=a ;
  ScrollBox1.HorzScrollBar.Position:=b ;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Without hacking into VCL/deriving custom components there's only one solution -  TForm.SetFocusedControl override + re-setting the positions of scrollbars as said above. One thing I added is disabling/enabling window redraw to avoid ugly jumps.
Here's my final snippet:

sbContainer is TScrollBox and NoScrCtrl is a control laying inside it which gets focus but we don't want it to be scrolled-in-view.

```
function TForm1.SetFocusedControl(Control: TWinControl): Boolean;
var hpos, vpos: integer;
begin
  if Control = NoScrCtrl then
  begin
    sbContainer.Perform(WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(False), 0);
    hpos := sbContainer.HorzScrollBar.Position;
    vpos := sbContainer.VertScrollBar.Position;
    Result := inherited SetFocusedControl(Control);
    sbContainer.HorzScrollBar.Position := hpos;
    sbContainer.VertScrollBar.Position := vpos;
    sbContainer.Perform(WM_SETREDRAW, WPARAM(True), 0);
    sbContainer.Refresh;
  end
  else
    Result := inherited SetFocusedControl(Control);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable scroll-into-view behavior from my main form, I used this solution: (C++Builder)

```
bool __fastcall TMainForm::SetFocusedControl(TWinControl *Control) {
    LockWindowUpdate(Handle);
    int vpos = VertScrollBar->Position;
    int hpos = HorzScrollBar->Position;
    bool result = TForm::SetFocusedControl(Control);
    if (VertScrollBar->Position != vpos) {
        VertScrollBar->Position = vpos;
    }
    if (HorzScrollBar->Position != hpos) {
        HorzScrollBar->Position = hpos;
    }
    LockWindowUpdate(0);
    return result;
}
```