# Disable autochange scrollbar position (disable scroll to active control)

Tags: delphi, focus, scrollbar, frame

I develop my applicatioin on Delphi XE3. I have frame with very long table (string grid) - about 10000 pixels in height (but height of frame much shorter). Because of other elements on frame (buttons and so on) I can't use scroll bar of grid and use it from frame. For this I set frame's property AutoScroll=True. But what the problem. When table get focus then frame's scroll bar scrolls to zero position. It's very unusefull, for example, I set scroll bar in half position, switch to another frame (I have some count of frames in pages of TPageControl), and when back to first frame I see, that scroll bar in zero position.

How I could understand, when some object on frame get focus the frame (because of AutoScroll=True property) try show that object at all. But because object big (I repeat the table has height about 10000 pixels), frame set scroll bar to zero position (i.e. scroll position changed).

So, how I can disable that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the same question here [How can I disable the scroll-into-view behavior of TScrollBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118194/how-can-i-disable-the-scroll-into-view-behavior-of-tscrollbox)
In my case I use override AutoScrollInView procedure. Disable implemention of this procedure at all.

```
procedure TfrSection.AutoScrollInView(AControl: TControl);
begin
//  inherited;
end;
```

It works.